# .gitignore file not working in Aptana 3

Tags: git, version-control, github, aptana, aptana3

I'm having issues with Aptana 3.  I can git clone a project from github.  But my issue is that the gitignore file is not working properly.  When I modify a file that is in the gitignore list, it still shows it in a modify or commit list.

If I do a git init through the console, the Aptana ui doesn't show file modifications.  When I initialize it through the UI, then files that are modified show the asterisk when modified, but the gitignore file (preexisting from the github repository) is not working.  Is there an easy way around this?

Thanks.

example in my gitignore file

```
config/database.yml
```

Modifying this file still shows 
[image]

Git status returns the following...

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   .gitignore
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   Gemfile.lock
#       modified:   config/database.yml
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .project
```

Comment: Can you please post your .gitignore file and the filename that is commited?

Comment: photo with snippet of code added

Comment: Can you also paste the command line output of `git status` on the console from where-ever aptana has hidden the repository.

Answer (score 3):

config/database.yml has already been committed.  At this point .gitignore is no longer involved.  *.gitignore only applies to files not yet tracked by git.*  If you have custom modifications to files which you do not wish to share, see https://gist.github.com/1423106 for ways people have worked around the problem.

Comment: +1 thanks, the statement ".gitignore only applies to files not yet tracked by git" helped me figure out a resolution.

Comment: nevermind after doing a pull it's coming back with the same issue again :(

Comment: Perhaps you should either create a new question or update this one with the protocol you were attempting to use to bypass the modify-tracked-files problem.  Note that I'm not aware of anything that works other than the techniques described in the link I included.

Answer (score 1):

You might have been bit by a problem that I just saw here. It looks like as of build 3.2.2.201208201020, if you open the commit window, then edit gitignore you have to restart Aptana before it will pick up the changes.

If you commit without restarting it will whatever is in the commit window regardless of what's in .gitignore :(

As for getting your file out of git, the following commands should help

```
cp config/database.yml config/database.yml.example # backup the file
git rm config/database.yml # remove the original from git
git commit -m "Untrack database.yml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to locally commit your `.gitignore` file in order to have Aptana ignore the files.

Just be careful to not push it to the origin.